# T-SQL shape table in desired form

Tags: sql, t-sql, pivot

I've got two tables: TableA and TableB

TableA: columnBLA, objName, objID

TableB: objID, ColumnIndex, StringValue, NumberValue, DateValue

```
TableA has a row: bla, Object Name, 21

TableB also has data for objID=21:

21, 1, a, NULL, NULL
21, 1, b, NULL, NULL
21, 1, c, NULL, NULL
21, 2, NULL, 11, NULL
21, 2, NULL, 22, NULL
21, 2, NULL, 33, NULL
21, 3, NULL, NULL, 1/1/2012
21, 3, NULL, NULL, 1/1/2013
21, 3, NULL, NULL, 1/1/2014
```

Now I want to reshape this data to the following form:

```
a, 11, 1/1/2012
b, 22, 1/1/2013
c, 33, 1/1/2014
```

I've got this far:

```
Select StringValue, NumberValue, DateValue
From
(Select StringValue
From TableA ta WITH (NOLOCK), TableB tb WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ta.objID = tb.objID
AND t.objName = N'Object Name'
AND d.ColumnIndex = 1) As StringValues
,
(Select NumberValue
From TableA ta WITH (NOLOCK), TableB tb WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ta.objID = tb.objID
AND t.objName = N'Object Name'
AND d.ColumnIndex = 2) As NumberValues
,
(Select DateValue
From TableA ta WITH (NOLOCK), TableB tb WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE ta.objID = tb.objID
AND t.objName = N'Object Name'
AND d.ColumnIndex = 1) As DateValues
```

But I got unwanted result.
Somebody told me I should use a PIVOT for that, but My SQL knowledge doesn't span that far.

Comment: please could you elaborate some more on what you are wanting out of the result. I ask this as in your sample output, you want "c" to have the value of "33" where as this is associated to "b" in the data. It would help if you could explain a little further.

Comment: Hi SQLGuru, I want to create a view for a specific objID=21. There are many more objIDs, but the view I'm creating is for the objID=21. The answer below from bluefeet answers my question perfectly, so thanks for your help, but it's already solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using both an `UNPIVOT` and a `PIVOT`:

```
select objid, stringvalue, numbervalue, datevalue
from
(
  select objid, col, value,
    row_number() over(partition by objid, col order by value) rn
  from
  (
    select a.objid,
      b.stringvalue,
      b.numbervalue,
      b.datevalue
    from tablea a
    left join tableb b
      on a.objid = b.objid
  ) src
  unpivot
  (
    value
    for col in (stringvalue, numbervalue, datevalue)
  ) unpiv
) s
pivot
(
  max(value)
  for col in (stringvalue, numbervalue, datevalue)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/632ab/5). The *unpivot* takes the values from your separate columns and converts it into rows. I then apply a `row_number()` to the data and then apply the *pivot* to turn it back into columns.

Another way to do this without using the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` functions is to apply a `row_number()` and then use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
select objid,
  max(case when columnindex = 1 then stringvalue end) stringvalue,
  max(case when columnindex = 2 then numbervalue end) numbervalue,
  max(case when columnindex = 3 then datevalue end) datevalue
from
(
  select a.objid,
    b.stringvalue,
    b.numbervalue,
    b.datevalue,
    b.columnindex,
    row_number() over(partition by a.objid, b.columnindex 
                      order by b.columnindex) rn
  from tablea a
  left join tableb b
    on a.objid = b.objid
) src
group by objid, rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/632ab/12)

The result of both query is:

```
| OBJID | STRINGVALUE | NUMBERVALUE | DATEVALUE |
-------------------------------------------------
|    21 |           a |          11 |  1/1/2012 |
|    21 |           b |          22 |  1/1/2013 |
|    21 |           c |          33 |  1/1/2014 |
```

Comment: Thanks bluefeet.

You're a great help. I've just tried your code and it works! Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Using `CTE` and `row_number()`. [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/630f7/29)

```
;with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by columnIndex 
                            order by StringValue, NumberValue, DateValue) rn,
  StringValue, NumberValue, DateValue
  from tableB tb join tableA ta on tb.objId = ta.objid
)
select t1.StringValue, t2.NumberValue, t3.DateValue
from cte t1 join cte t2 on t1.rn = t2.rn 
            join cte t3 on t1.rn = t3.rn 
where not (t1.stringValue is null or t2.numberValue is null or t3.datevalue is null)
order by t1.stringValue
```

Comment: Hi Kaf,

Thanks for your solution. I didn't test it as I got it working already with bluefeet's solution.
I didn't even know the "with" operator in sql, nor did I ever hear of cte.
One can do great things with tsql, once one knows all the operators and such. I'm a C#.NET programmer with only basic SQL knowledge. I really appreciate all you guys answering my question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tested with your own data. Click the link `Fiddle Demo` above if you like to see it's working.